# PHP remove undefined offset:

Tags: php, loops, while-loop

I would like to ask what is this kind of error undefined offset:4

my code is

```
$url = 'http://gogo.com, http://yoyo.com, http://gogo.com, http://yoyo.com, http://gogo.com, http://yoyo.com';
$key = 'key1, key2, key3';


$xurl = explode( "\n", $url );
$xkey = explode( "\n", $key );

$count = count( $xkey );
echo $count;
$i = 0;

while ( $i <= $count ) {
    if(empty($xkey[$i])){
        unset($xkey[$i]);
    }

    echo $xkey[$i];

$i++;   
}
```

the echo is `key1 key2 key3`

but the thing is that i need to loop the xkey equal to my url
so the echo should be but i only have 3keyword i mean the keyword is less than the url.

how can i make it something like this below...

```
http://gogo.com - key1
http://yoyo.com - key2
http://gogo.com - key3
http://yoyo.com - key1
http://gogo.com - key2
http://yoyo.com - key3
```

Comment: You're using <= in your while loop. Only < is needed because you begin couting with 0. So 3 items will result in the indexes 0,1 and 2.

Answer (score 4):

What it means is that the script is looking for the value of `$xkey[4]`, but that element doesn't exist.  This is happening because array keys like this are 0-based, so the fourth element will be `$xkey[3]`.  Change your while statement to `while ( $i < $count )` as count will be 4, but the max key will be 3.

Comment: +1 - It is important to note that this only holds true for a 0-indexed array with contiguous keys. In this case this will always be true of the input array, because you are working directly with the result of `explode()`, but it's not true everywhere and falls apart completely with associative arrays. This is why in general, if you want to iterate an array, the safest looping construct to use is `foreach`. It also has the nice side effect of creating much tidier looking code.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing

```
while ( $i <= $count ) {
```

where $count is the number of element in $xkey (let say 4 elements)
As arrays are 0 indexed, the element $xkey[3] is the 4th and last element.

$xkey[4] will bring you that error.

Now, delete "=" in this `while ( $i <= $count ) {` and it should disappear.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where to start explaining what your problem is, you have an entirely wrong approach. To get the result you want you need to do this:

```
$urlString = 'http://gogo.com, http://yoyo.com, http://gogo.com, http://yoyo.com, http://gogo.com, http://yoyo.com';
$keyString = 'key1, key2, key3';

$urls = explode(',', $urlString);
$keys = explode(',', $keyString);

$i = 0;
$count = count($keys);

foreach ($urls as $url) {
    echo $url, ' - ', $keys[$i % $count], PHP_EOL;
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: So you've finally joined the 100K club. Have another 10 from me. Nice use of modulus, I always forget about it for some reason, and even when I remember I have to stop and do some maths...

Comment: Thanks. Explanation for downvote by somebody else would be nice too.